# YQL showing results from multiple sources

Tags: yql

select * from people

```
<root>
<row>
  <name>a</name>
  <address>address1</address>
  <loc_id>1</loc_id>
</row>
<row>
  <name>b</name>
  <address>address2</address>
  <loc_id>2</loc_id>
</row>
</root>
```

select * from locations

```
<root>
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>location1</name>
  <details>locationdetails1</details>
</row>
<row>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>location2</name>
  <details>locationdetails2</details>
</row>
</root>
```

Is there anyway in YQL where we can join both these data sources on people.loc_id<->location.id and return a result that includes all the values together. I know there is a possibility of naming conflicts but anyway of resolving that too? So basically any yql query that might help return results like below or something similar.

```
<root>
<row>
  <name>a</name>
  <address>address1</address>
  <loc_id>1</loc_id>
  <location.id>1</location.id>
  <location.name>location1</location.name>
  <location.details>locationdetails1</location.details>
</row>
<row>
  <name>b</name>
  <address>address2</address>
  <loc_id>2</loc_id>
  <location.id>2</location.id>
  <location.name>location2</location.name>
  <location.details>locationdetails2</location.details>
</row>
</root>
```

Cross-posted on [YQL forums](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/YQL-showing-results-from-multiple-sources/1408421828472-1b9ebea3-950f-492d-b502-999f68e9d98f)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible directly in YQL. It doesn't have the ability to combine results like this.

Instead in your application (whatever you have that is calling in to YQL) could make two calls and combine the results.